# Make the edge of a model smoother

Tags: mesh, edges, photogrammetry

I have a mesh that resulted out of a photogrametrie and that I'm editing in blender. I'm trying to remove the scattered part of the edge at the end of the mesh so that the mesh has a smooth end (as indicated by the red line in the picture). Does anybody know a good way how to achieve this in blender (other than manipulating each and every vertex)
[image: My mesh]

Comment: You can enter sculpt mode and smooth those vertices with Smooth brush (Shift+Left click) while adjusting brush radius. It's possible to enable Dyntopo (dynamic topology) in Sculpt mode which will edit topology based on brush size / existing details size. Another not always acceptable option is to rebuild the scan if too many details need to be edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could draw a curve with grease pencil(<kbd>d</kbd>), making sure it would hold the part that needs to be cut away inside if it was closed, convert it to a curve select it and then the object so the object is active and enter edit mode and just use knife project. You don't need to use grease pencil and could create the curve some other way as well.

[image]

Grease pencil smoothing functionality might also be useful:

[image]

Comment: This looks like the solution I have been searching for but I'm not quite able to reproduce it. After I drew the curve with the grease pencil it is not selected and I don't find how to select it for transformation. Is there a trick? Sorry for the stupid questions but blender is really new for me. I'm using blender 2.79b.

Comment: Grease pencil does not need to be selected, it is not the same as an object. When you draw it, a new grease pencil layer is created and it is active already since it is the only one there. You can see me deleting the grease pencil layer in the n panel after the conversion in the GIF.

Comment: Thanks! I can reproduce it now! Basically that is what I'm after but I'm having a bit trouble to draw a nice curve. Is there any way to edit the curve after I drew it?

Comment: It is quite easy to edit the Curve object that you convert the Grease pencil stroke to, just hit tab to enter edit mode and you can edit the vertices of the curve. You can convert it to Bezier Curve if you need it smoother. Also have a look at the t panel,Grease Pencil tab for grease pencil properties once you create a grease pencil layer in the n panel Drawing Brushes section with smoothing options at the bottom appears - you can smooth the strokes as they are drawn. I find it to be one of the easiest ways to make nice smooth curves.

Comment: I added a GIF showing how to smooth grease pencil strokes to the answer.

Comment: Cool stuff! This getting better and better! Is it also possible to re-smooth the curve after I corrected a few vertices?

Comment: You can manipulate the curve objects in all the usual ways curve objects can be manipulated - you could use proportional editing for example, or convert it to polygon edge(alt+c), simplify it with limited dissolve, convert it back to curve and set spline type to bezier to have bezier handles. But these are separate questions.